# Integration inside a root-find function

Tags: r, integral, root-finding

I am trying to code a root finding algorithm in `R` that will solve an equation of the form:

> integral from xinitial->x of f(x) = a

with inputs of `xinitial`, `a` and the form of function `f(x)`.

Do I need to use `vectorize` to set up the integral values prior to running them through the root finding algorithm?

Example: y=x x1=1 a=2 I was trying to set up the root find to output the value of x2 at which the integral, ((x2^2)/2 )=a+(x1^2)/2.

Tried using

```
a<-1.5  
ftn<-function(x)return(x)  
f<-function(x)return(-a+integrate(ftn,1,x)$value +0)  
uniroot( f, c(0, 4) )
```

Comment: I don't understand the notation "integral(f(xinitial))". An integral always has a lower **and** upper limit. Do you want to solve integral_x1^x2 f(x) dx = a numerically for x2? Please provide an example.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for response, edited above

Comment: And why are you not satisfied with the output of your code?

Comment: Ya realized after editing and running more values it was working. Have another issue but unrelated, thanks for your response.

Comment: side note : `ftn <- function(x) return(x)  ` base r already has a function that return the passed in value `base::identity` ; also function and explicit return is relatively bloated i.e. `\(x){-a+integrate(identity,1,x)$value} ` gives the same

Answer (score 0):

```
ftn <- function(x) return(x)  
f <- function(x) return(-a+integrate(ftn, x1, x)$value)  
uniroot(f, c(0, 4))
```